# Business Central - xmlport import csv

Tags: import, dynamics-business-central

I have a CSV file as below and I'm trying and failing to import it into BC table: "Gen. Journal Line" (81) using an XmlPort.

```
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","","","95.460","01/01/2018"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","","-5.370","31/01/2018"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","REVERSING ENTRY","5.370","01/02/2018"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","","-8.500","28/02/2018"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","REVERSING ENTRY","8.500","01/03/2018"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","","-5.760","10/10/2019"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","","-5.760","10/10/2019"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","REVERSING ENTRY","5.760","01/05/2019"
"GENERAL","DEFAULT","TLPUK0099","Revalued Source","REVERSING ENTRY","5.760","01/05/2019"
```

Here's my XmlPort:-

```
xmlport 50000 XmlPortGenJrnl
{
    Format = FixedText;
    Direction = Import;
    TextEncoding = UTF8;
    UseRequestPage = false;
    TableSeparator = '';

    schema
    {
        textelement(Root)
        {
            tableelement(GenJournalLine; "Gen. Journal Line")
            {
                XmlName = 'GenJnlLine';
                fieldelement(JournalTemplateName; GenJournalLine."Journal Template Name") { }
                fieldelement(JournalBatchName; GenJournalLine."Journal Batch Name") { }
                fieldelement(AccNum; GenJournalLine."Account No.") { }
                fieldelement(Description; GenJournalLine.Description) { }
                fieldelement(DocumentNo; GenJournalLine."Document No.") { }
                fieldelement(Amount; GenJournalLine.Amount) { }
                fieldelement(PostingDate; GenJournalLine."Posting Date") { }
            }
        }
    }

    var
        myInt: Integer;
}
```

When I call `XmlPort.Run(50000, false, true);` in a Page extension action, I get **error: Posting Date must have a value in Gen. Journal Line: Journal Template Name=, Journal Batch Name=, Line No.=0. It cannot be zero or empty.**

Where am I going wrong? Posting Date does have a value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must change `Format = FixedText` to `Format = VariableText`.
`FixedText` indicates that all lines have exactly the same length, which your lines do not.

Additionally you might need to tell it how to split the lines by setting the `FieldSeparator` and `FieldDelimeter`:

```
FieldDelimeter = '"';
FieldSeparator = ",";
```